# neovim not importing modules

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm trying to move over to use lua files for neovim config however I've encountered a problem.

I have two files in `~/.config/nvim/` `init.vim` and `lsp.lua`. The `init.vim` file contains the line `lua require('lsp')`.

this works fine if I am in the the `~/.config/nvim` directory when I launch nvim. However, if I launch nvim from any other directory I get an error on startup

```
Error detected while processing /Users/mds31/.config/nvim/init.vim:                                                                      
line   33:                                                                                                                               
E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: module 'lsp' not found: 
        no field package.preload['lsp']                                                                                                  
        no file './lsp.lua'                                                                                                              
        no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/lsp.lua'                                                                            
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lsp.lua'                                                                                       
        no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lsp/init.lua'                                                                                  
        no file './lsp.so'                                                                                                               
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lsp.so'                                                                                          
        no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'                                                                                      
stack traceback:                                                                                                                         
        [C]: in function 'require'                                                                                                       
        [string ":lua"]:1: in main chunk
```

I presume this is a problem with relative imports but having searched for a solution all of the guides suggest that there is no problem with this setup. Am I missing some crucial bit of config?

=== Edit ===

using the following command

```
:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.api.nvim_list_runtime_paths()))
```

I found `"/Users/mds31/.config/nvim"` as the first entry

despite this running the command `:lua require('lsp')` fails with the same error as above

Answer (score 2):

Turns out yes I was missing key bit of setup info. Neovim apparently updates the lua `package.path` by appending `lua/?.lua` to each runtime path https://neovim.io/doc/user/lua.html. So I needed to move lsp.lua into `~/.config/nvim/lua/lsp.lua` then everything works fine.